# Have formula to remove all characters to the right of the last char (there might be more then one) problems with vba

Tags: excel, vba

The formula `=LEFT(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))))-1)` to remove all characters to the right of the `last` `.` (there might be more then one) works if I add it to a cell and copy down.

I can not figure out how add the formula to vba

I have the vba if there is only one `.`

(the cells to be evaluated are in column A and the output is to column E )
When I add the code ta a module `c.Formula = "=LEFT(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))))-1)"` it highlights in red and error `Invalid Character` with the `|` highligthed

Thanks

```
Sub NotWorking()
Dim c As range
Dim Lastrow As Long

With Sheets("sheet1")
    Lastrow = .range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In .range("E2:E" & Lastrow)
        c.Formula = "=LEFT(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))))-1)"
    Next
    .range("E1").Value = "Source"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to double-up on the double quotes within the formula.

Comment: as Gary'sStudent mentioned, yous should use: `c.Formula = "=LEFT(A2,FIND(""|"",SUBSTITUTE(A2,""."",""|"",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,""."",""""))))-1)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First tip:**

when your are usign quotes in formula in VBA, you should use double qoutes. E.g.

instead

```
Range("E1").Formula="=IF(A1="test",1,2)"
```

you should use

```
Range("E1").Formula="=IF(A1=""test"",1,2)"
```

**Second tip:**

There is no need to use loop when applying formula. There is a more efficient way to do it.

Next your code

```
For Each c In .range("E2:E" & Lastrow)
    c.Formula = "=LEFT(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,".","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))))-1)"
Next
```

gives you formula for `E2` : `=LEFT(A2,...)`, and formula for `E3` again `=LEFT(A2,...)` (note in both formulas `A2`). I think, it's not what you expected. Use this one instead:

```
.Range("E2:E" & Lastrow).Formula="=LEFT(A2,FIND(""|"",SUBSTITUTE(A2,""."",""|"",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,""."",""""))))-1)"
```

Above code applies formula to entire range. Formula would be adjusted for each row, e.g. formula for `E2` would be `=LEFT(A2,...)`, while formula for `E3` would be `=LEFT(A3,...)` and so on.

But, if you need to have *the same formula* for entire column `E` (for `E2` : `=LEFT(A2,...)`, and for `E3` again `=LEFT(A2,...)`), use absolute/mixed references (with `$` sign):

```
.Range("E2:E" & Lastrow).Formula="=LEFT(A$2,FIND(""|"",SUBSTITUTE(A$2,""."",""|"",LEN(A$2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$2,""."",""""))))-1)"
```

Comment: Thanks simoco, I am confused on when to use a loop and when(if ever) not to as most of what I know comes from forums and googling and most stuff I read uses loops so I use loops so I appreciate your comments

Comment: @Tim, in all cases when it's possible not to use loop - don't use it:) When you apply same formula for entire range it's better to use `Range("A1:A10").Formula="=Left(A2,...)"` rather than use loop. I've updated my asnwer with some details what your loop actually does and to do it in the most sound way

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points @Simoco makes, you need to adjust the cell refernces in order to get the same effect copying a range gives you, as Excel will automatically adjust these for you (unless you use absolute refernces `$`), whereas VBA won't.

The easiest way to do this is to use the `R1C1` version of cell references.

Try this

```
Sub Working()
    Dim rng As Range
    With Sheets("sheet1")
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(, 2))
    End With
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC1,FIND(""|"",SUBSTITUTE(RC1,""."",""|"",LEN(RC1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC1,""."",""""))))-1)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank Chris, I just had found this `http://excelmate.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/excel-r1c1-reference-style-vs-a1/` on `R1C1` which I am hoping will make the use of R1C1 clear to me.